# Update pandas dataframe values with if else condition?

Tags: python, pandas

I want update a pandas dataframe column where it's boolean value is True / False. JSON format is

```
[
  {
   "A":"value",
   "TIME":1551052800000,
   "C":35,
   "D":36,
   "E":34,
   "F":35,
   "G":33
  },
 ...
...
]
```

Converted it into dataframe

`df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(content)`

I can now access different columns in the original object via the dataframe as

`df["TIME"] = '2019-12-0'`

If i do the above it basically gets set for all the df["TIME"] in the dataframe. I want to update only specific columns where a condition matches say

```
If df["label"].bool() == True
   then update 5 columns in x way
Else if df["label"].bool() == False
   then update 6 columns in a different way
```

I run simple if else condition.

```
       if df["label"].bool() == True:
            df["A"] = df["G"]
            if df["A"] == 0 :
                print(df["A"])
            else:
                df["C"] = (df["D"]/df["E"])*100
        elif df["label"].bool() == False:
            ....
```

It works fine for 1 selection, but for multiple selection it returns

`ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous.`

Note: df["label"] column is added from the client to check a specific row is selected or not

Comment: Could you expand on your question? 

Perhaps provide an example input dataframe and your expected output.

Comment: Updated the question a bit

Comment: df["label'] is column in a dataframe, and one column is a series. A series contains many items. Determining True of False across an entire series is ambiguous. To get single (scalar) items, us df.at['2019-02-01', 'label'] == True

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you are better setting relevant slices of the dataframe ([indexing](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html)), as opposed to setting the values with if/else statements.

For example,

```
# df = a pandas.DataFrame
df.loc[:,'A'][df['label']=='value'] = 0
```

**Note:** If `df['label']` just contains Boolean values you don't need to check its value and could just use it directly to mask the dataframe:

```
df.loc[:,'A'][df['label']] = 0
```

Comment: This code works great for updating a single column but what if i want to update two more columns?

Say something like 

`df.loc[:,'A'][df['label']=='value'] = df['A'] = 99 & df['B'] = 900`

Comment: Basically the label value is needed as a check to update multiple column/series value in the dataframe. Like say I have 6 columns, namely A,B,C,D,E,F and based on label i need to update most of these columns

Comment: One way would be to use the 'mask' multiple times:
`df.loc[:,'A'][df['label']=='value'] = 99`


`df.loc[:,'B'][df['label']=='value'] = 900`


But you could probably do it in a cleaner way!

Comment: That seems to be the only solution for now. Thanks for the answer anyhow. Appreciate it.

Comment: You could iterate over the columns so  you don't have to write it multiple times. I.e.,

`columns = ['A', 'B']

values = [99,900]

for col, value in zip(columns,values):


       df.loc[:,col] = value`


where you can add your condition as above.